# tr command not working as expected

Tags: bash, tr

I have the following string:

```
"Last updated Unknown </DIV> </DIV></DIV></TD></TR></TABLE></FORM></DIV></BODY></HTML>"
```

and I am trying a simple example to replace HTML with test
but if I try this example I get a unexpected results:

```
echo "Last updated Unknown</DIV></DIV></DIV></TD></TR></TABLE></FORM></DIV></BODY></HTML>" | tr "HTML" "test"
```

Result:

```
tast updated Unknown </DIV> </DIV></DIV></eD></ eR></eABtE></FORs></DIV></BODY></test>
```

Comment: If it doesn't work as expected, the expectations are wrong. It works as designed.

Comment: I've edited your question to use code blocks so you can write HTML tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tr` is used to translate or delete characters. Try `sed` instead:

```
sed 's/HTML/test/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

`tr "HTML" "test"` replaces `H` by `t`, `T` by `e`, `M` by `s` and `L` by `t`.

You could use `sed` instead.

```
$ echo "Last updated Unknown </DIV> </DIV></DIV></TD></TR></TABLE></FORM></DIV></BODY></HTML>" | sed 's/HTML/test/g'
Last updated Unknown </DIV> </DIV></DIV></TD></TR></TABLE></FORM></DIV></BODY></test>
```